# ANAGRAM in a REBUS

Tags: visual, rebus, anagram

Given below is a picture.
Find the word(s), and use it/them to find the name of a famous personality.

[image]

Hint 1

> The personality is Indian i.e. from India, and perhaps one of the most famous Indian around the world right now.

Hint 2

> That in the picture, is not Chinese ;P

Good Luck!

Comment: Title was a dead giveaway...For your future puzzles I would suggest you to keep the answer in the mystery

Comment: @manshu Sure! I'll keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> Narendra Modi, prime minister of India

The image is two parts:

> MANDARIN and REDO, which together comprise the letters in NARENDRA MODI