# Mathematics is Prohibited

Tags: visual, rebus, anagram

Find that name which hides within this image.
Hint

> It is a city. And somewhere on the lines of [my last picture puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28577/anagram-in-a-rebus).

[image]

Good Luck!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word is

> BANGALORE

As before, there are two keywords

> **ALGEBRA** and **NO**, which contain the letters in **BANGALORE**

Answer (score 3):

I found the name.

> AL

It wasn't all that hidden though.